# Why does classnotfoundexception come up, AFTER removed from manifest

Tags: android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver in loader
```

This is the error i get. it doesnt do this when its beeing tested. only when installed in android market

I removed the `<receiver` from my manifest and then upgraded that application. and STILL getting this error on install. Its really annoying. someone please helper

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver in loader
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got hit with the same thing, if you had the previous AdMob sdk and upgraded, then you need to remove all of this in your Manifest.

```
<receiver 
android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver" 
android:exported="true"> 
<intent-filter> 
<action 
android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

More info https://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/cf3c87794dbfe3a6/5e37c95e51a051c5?lnk=raot&pli=1